# Unable to vite build for production in Laravel

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-livewire

I have a Laravel + Livewire app, that I'm trying to build for production.

I can successfully run `./vendor/bin/sail npm run build`:

```
./vendor/bin/sail npm run build

> build
> vite build

vite v3.2.7 building for production...
transforming (19) node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/buildURL.js
 daisyUI components 2.52.0  https://daisyui.com
  ✔︎ Including:  base, components, 2 themes, utilities
  ❤︎ Support daisyUI:  https://opencollective.com/daisyui 
  
✓ 60 modules transformed.
public/build/manifest.json             0.25 KiB
public/build/assets/app.bf5ec64f.css   80.27 KiB / gzip: 12.73 KiB
public/build/assets/app.8c40d1a4.js    143.69 KiB / gzip: 51.52 KiB
```

The assets are loaded in a blade layout using the @vite directive:

```
...
{{-- Scripts --}}
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
...
```

However when I view the page source, I can see it still references port 5173 (which would be the vite dev server):

```
<script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/@vite/client"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:5173/resources/css/app.css" /><script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

I was expecting to see a reference to `public/build/assets/...`

My vite.config.js is fairly simple:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    server: {
        hmr: {
            host: 'localhost',
        },
    }
});
```

The documents (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles) says that:

"In build mode, the directive will load your compiled and versioned assets, including any imported CSS."

...but it does not appear to be doing that.

How do I stop the @vite directive / vite from trying to use the vite dev server, and use the compiled assets? (As obviously, the vite server won't be running in prod).

I've tried `APP_DEBUG=false` and `APP_ENV=prod` in my .env, and `./vendor/bin/sail artisan view:clear` which makes no difference.

Deps are up to date: "laravel/framework": "^10.0", and "vite": "^3.2.7" (currently 4.4.2).

Comment: I normally do `npm run build` in root folder, and I don't have error.. try like this without using sail

Comment: Tried `npm run build` in root folder / outside of sail - still no difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out that if the 'hotfile' exists in `./public/hot` then the vite blade directive (see: `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php`) will try to look for the vite server and perform hot reloading.

Simply remove `./public/hot` and it all works fine!

Comment: It is true. I was looking for this for hours until after deleting the hot file, it now reads the sources from the build folder.

Comment: Oh dear... The file appeared persistent after running `vite build --watch` in Docker and stopping the container. It's probably so that the process inside the container did not trap its stopping completely: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/v5.0.10/packages/vite/src/node/server/index.ts#L632

Comment: Thank you so much. Saved my day with removing hot file